# Where does windows get the program name for the 'are you sure you want to run this program' dialog for downloaded exes?

Tags: windows, metadata, exe

On one of my projects, the downloaded installer file gives the internal name for the program name in the 'Do you want to run this software' warning dialog, rather than the external name. Where does windows get this program name from, as there's no sign of it in the standard metadata in the .exe properties?

Comment: What version of Windows?  How are you creating the executable?  I'm nearly certain the string you're seeing is being read out of your application manifest, but how to change that depends on where the manifest is coming from.

Comment: This is on windows vista. It's an exe created by our installer system on the build server, so the actual method is slightly obtuse

Answer (score 1):

There's all kinds of interesting information in the .EXE header. Maybe you can use this: http://www.brothersoft.com/dump-exe-file-header-189959.html to dump and view it.

Comment: Yes, the DLL or the EXE both have a header, with file name, project name, company name, copyright info, version header, etc.  Normally you set all of this in your project options for your compilations resources.  You can also setup locale-specific version blocks, and the OS will use that if the current locale matches (otherwise it uses the universal base one).

Comment: If you don't want to use a header dumper you can also open your .EXE file in Microsoft Word. It will look really strange but you should be able to pick out some strings. Just don't save the file after looking at it!